# How do I find URLs in a paragraph that don't have http:// or https:// and prepend them so that the protocols are correct?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, laravel

I have a request that is coming from a WYSIWYG editor that looks like this

```
"<p>Testing if urls work <a href=\"google.com\" rel=\"noopener noreferrer\" target=\"_blank\">google.com</a>google.com</p> this is some more content that might be added to the url <a href="www.google.com">www.Google.com</a> with some more text that follows. "
```

I have found plenty of examples where I could use regex to find URLs that have https or http, but nothing that seems to allow me to update those URLs inside of a paragraph. Ideally I'm looking at find anything that doesn't have http or https and prepend it to the URL. I don't mind applying a solution to the back-end or the front-end.

This is the result I'm looking to achieve

```
"<p>Testing if urls work <a href=\"https://google.com\" rel=\"noopener noreferrer\" target=\"_blank\">google.com</a>google.com</p> this is some more content that might be added to the url <a href="https://www.google.com">www.Google.com</a> with some more text that follows. "
```

Comment: well regex has replacement functionality built in... or you could try using a DOM parser instead

Comment: Can you show the result you want to get with example ?

Comment: I added the result example im looking for @hanifzekri

Comment: I think I'm just looking to find all the <a href=\" that dont have http or https after it.  So far I have this that helps /<a href=\\"/g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like this to convert your string as you need:

```
<?php

$str = '<p>Testing if urls work <a href=\"google.com\" rel=\"noopener noreferrer\" target=\"_blank\">google.com</a>google.com</p><p>Testing if urls work <a href=\"http://google.com\" rel=\"noopener noreferrer\" target=\"_blank\">google.com</a>google.com</p> this is some more content that might be added to the url <a href="https://www.google.com">www.Google.com</a> with some more text that follows.';

function checklinks($str){
    
    $str = str_replace("\\", "", $str);
    
    $callback = function($match){
        
        if (!preg_match('/https:\/\//i', $match[1])) {
            
            if (preg_match('/http:\/\//i', $match[1])) $urlstr = '<a href="https://' . substr($match[1], 7) . '"';
            elseif (preg_match('/http\/\//i', $match[1])) $urlstr = '<a href="https://' . substr($match[1], 6) . '"';
            else $urlstr = '<a href="https://' . $match[1] . '"';
        
        } else $urlstr = '<a href="' . $match[1] . '"';
        
        return $urlstr;
    };
    
    if (preg_match('/<a\s+href="([^"]+)"/i', $str)) {
        $str = preg_replace_callback('/<a\s+href="([^"]+)"/i', $callback, $str);
    }
    
    return $str;    
}

echo htmlentities($str) . '<br><br>';

echo htmlentities(checklinks($str));

?>
```

after using the function, the result will be :

```
<p>Testing if urls work <a href="https://google.com" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">google.com</a>google.com</p><p>Testing if urls work <a href="https://google.com" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">google.com</a>google.com</p> this is some more content that might be added to the url <a href="https://www.google.com">www.Google.com</a> with some more text that follows.
```

Comment: Awesome this worked out pretty good, i found one issue though which if you input a link that has the protocol it is stripping the colon so this link with https:// and www.google.com will turn into https//www.google.com

Comment: I edit update code. Also add sample for times that users may use wrong protocol like http//, You can add same "elseif" for any wrong combination you like.